# Azure cli command for deploying react.js code to node Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-web-app-service, gitlab-ci, azure-cli

The commands for deploying the zip file are clear, but it's unclear to me what the process would be for creating the appropriate zip file for a node project. Any help with this would be much appreciated. Here are some commands I've tried: `az webapp deployment source config-zip -n <app-name> -g <app-group> --src upload.zip` `az webapp deploy -n <app-name> -g <app-group> --src-path ./build`

Answer (score 0):

#### az webapp deploy

If you are using **`az webapp deploy`** for continuous Zip Deployment you have to add the **SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true** config either manually in a **portal** or using cli command **az webapp config appsettings set**

```
# To set config to enable build automation for ZIP deploy
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group  <group-name>  --name  <app-name>  --settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true
```

#### az webapp deployment

If you use  **az webapp deployment** the kudu zip push deployment for a web app deployment.

Kudu thinks that zip deployments do not require any build-related tasks such as **npm install** or dotnet publish by default. To enable Kudu detection logic and the build script creation process, include a **.deployment** file in your zip file with the following content: **`[config] SCM DO BUILD DURING DEPLOYMENT = true`**

If you want to use ZIP deployment for enable the build automation you can have to set the config
**SCM DO BUILD DURING DEPLOYMENT = true**.

#### Refereces

- [az web deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-a-zip-package)
- [az web deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: I would like to use `az webapp deploy` if possible. Do you know what the process is for creating the zip file? Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you are using local project you can zip from your side. if you want to download the project from azure portal you can follow [this](https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f) to download the zip.